# how to use call function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

undefined is printed instead of "Tester"

```
var sayName = () => {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
};

const person = {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'age': 34
};

sayName.call(person)
```

Expected to print "

```
My name is Tester
```

"
but got

```
My name is undefined
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `this`. Change it to a regular function and it will work.

Comment: If you change it from a function expression to a function declaration it will work since arrow functions don't maintain their own `this` context.